How can we know that a model is a valid model for a given set of axioms?
For a while I have thought (naively) that maths is constructed in the following way: pick a set of axioms and some rules of logic, then deduce all the theorems you can about it. The goal being obviously to have the simplest set of axioms (and simplest logic rules?) such that you recover the mathematical structure that we like.
Trying to understand Gödel's theorems recently, I realized there is a third ingredient: the models. The typical example being Peano arithmetic, first-order logic (or second-order? I'm confused there), and the standard integers, together forming the usual basis for addition, multiplication, and eventually a lot of the usual maths.
Buut, there is a step I don't see how to formalize: how does one prove that a model is valid for a given set of axioms? How do we know for sure that the model for standard integers (with addition and multiplication) is a model of Peano axioms?
To prove something formally in maths, I thought one would just show it follows from the chosen set of axioms. However, one cannot use any axiom here, since we don't want to assume and use them but prove they are always satisfied in the model -without using any other axiom, only the chosen logic.
Does it have to be constructive proofs? How does one prove that something is true for any integer (in the model) without using any axiom ?

The following explanation from a colleague will stick with me forever: "a group is a model of the group axioms, in the same way that a model of ZFC is a model of the ZFC axioms".

This is perhaps not emphasized enough in introductory logic textbooks, but when you define the syntax and semantics of (first order) logic, there are two distinct definitions with different goals, that you should have in mind.
The first one is formalizing mathematics, as you said

pick a set of axioms and some rules of logic, then deduce all the theorems you can about it.

Here only the syntax part of the definition makes sense, i.e what strings count as formulas and what strings count as proofs (usually lists of formulas built from the axioms and Modus Ponens.)
In this case you can interpret strings as literal symbols on a piece of paper or some similar medium, with the definitions giving you an algorithm to decide when a string is a valid proof. Obviously these symbols have intended interpretations such as conjunction, negation etc. but ultimately you have complete philosophical freedom to interpret what this pushing around of symbols actually means.
Note that models are defined in terms of sets, and semantically the truth value of a formula is defined by being true in all models. But if you're trying to define math (especially using ZFC) from the ground up you can't assume to know what a set is, that would be dumb!
The second goal is what logicians are actually concerned with most of the time, which is proving meta-theorems, that is proving things about provability and such. In this case you assume you have a meta-theory which you can formalize your arguments in (i.e. ZFC with symbols on literal paper in the above sense.) And then define the syntax of formulas and proofs again, except now you have to model strings in your meta-theory somehow, for example in ZFC you can take some finite set to be an alphabet and define strings to be ordered tuples over that, which would ultimately be just a set as everything is in ZFC.
Now the definition of a model, and thus the semantics of logic, also makes sense and you can now study how the syntax and semantics relate, but all of this will depend on your meta-theory.
So, let's say you wanted to formalize the completeness theorem of first order logic, that is a first order statement is provable from a set of axioms $\Sigma$ iff it is true in every model of $\Sigma.$
To do this you would pick a meta-theory $L_1,$ say ZFC with literal symbols on paper, inside this you would define first order logic, encoding strings as sets, and define axioms to get a first order theory $L_2,$ so that the sentences  of $L_2$ are sets in $L_1$ which you refer to by using symbols on paper. Now you can write down the statement of the theorem in $L_1$ using paper, but in this statement 'formula' now refers to the formulas of $L_2$ that is sets discussed by $L_1.$
You can do the same thing for Gödel's incompleteness theorem.
You can also stack more theories into each other by taking $L_1$ and $L_2$ as before and defining logic and ZFC in $L_2$ you would get an $L_3$. Now to formalize a sentence of $L_3$ you would need to write formulas on paper in your $L_1$ which would encode the sets used to define your strings in your $L_2,$ with these in turn encoding the sets of $L_2$ that serve as the strings of your $L_3.$

Thanks a lot for this detailed answer!
I reckon you gave me exactly the bit I was missing by mentioning this meta-theory $L_1$, that then allows you to prove things rigorously in your theory $L_2$.
So if I understand correctly, if I want to prove that a model I defined for natural numbers satisfy the Peano axioms, I would do it inside a particular set of axioms and a logic I've chosen, correct?
On which meta-axioms and meta-logic does Gödel theorems take place? As far as I understood you need axioms giving you natural numbers, addition and multiplication. What about the logic?


So if I understand correctly, if I want to prove that a model I defined for natural numbers satisfy the Peano axioms, I would do it inside a particular set of axioms and a logic I've chosen, correct?
Yes.
On which meta-axioms and meta-logic does Gödel theorems take place?
As is custom in math, this is not specified I believe, but it can surely be formalized in ZF. Probably something weaker even, because Gödel's original proof is often preferred to the non-constructive but super simple proof using Turing machines.


Another comment about this bit: "this meta-theory $L_1$, that then allows you to prove things rigorously in your theory $L_2$." You only need a meta theory when you want to prove things \textit{about} the system, like what it can and cannot prove, or when talking about it's models. You can formalize most proofs straight in the system that's being written down on paper, like $1+1=2$ from the first order Peano axioms or pretty much any theorem of math that's not logic or set theory from ZFC.
